# Upload file(s) using react-bootstrap FormControl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap

I have created a form in react application using react-bootstrap in which I select files to be uploaded using the following `FormControl`:

```
<FormGroup>
    <ControlLabel>Photos</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl name="images[]" type="file" multiple onChange={this.handlePhotos}/>
</FormGroup>
```

where my handlePhotos function is:

```
handlePhotos(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let files = event.target.files;

    if(files && files.length > 0)
    {
       this.setState({device_photos: files});
    }
    else
        console.log("no files selected");
    }
}
```

But when I make post request to my backend using axios, the photos parameters seems to be empty. Can someone suggest how to fetch files and set them in state variables to be uploaded via post request?

Comment: Did you use "FormData" to send ajax request to server ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried using FormData first but it had the same issue. It only worked when I used simple HTML 'form' tag with 'action' attribute pointing to the post URL.

Comment: any resolution on this?